Why are "Chagossians" considered indigenous to Chagos Islands despite having spent less than 200 years there?
According to Wikipedia, the ancestors of the Chagossians first arrived on the islands in 1793 as slaves for French coconut plantations. Their descendants were expelled in 1965, meaning their total presence on the islands lasted at most 172 years. Throughout this period, the islands were under French or British control, leaving the Chagossians with 0 years of sovereign rule over the territory.
This brief tenure makes the Chagossians' claim to indigeneity uniquely short compared to other recognized indigenous peoples worldwide. Only two other groups have inhabited their territories for less than a millennium, and both arrived as independent settlers rather than as slaves:

Inuit (Greenland): Migrated from Alaska around 1200 CE, at a time when Norse settlers had already staked a claim. After Norse colonies vanished in the early 15th century, the Inuit had about 300 years of de facto independence before Denmark reasserted control in 1721. Their claim is likewise contentious, as Europeans (led by Erik the Red around 982 CE) had settled Greenland roughly two centuries before the Inuit arrival, making it a unique example of reverse colonization.

Maori (New Zealand): Arrived circa 1300 CE and maintained independence until British colonization in 1840. Total period of sovereignty: 540 years; overall presence: 700 years.


All other recognized indigenous cultures have inhabited their lands for at least a millennium, so their claims are clear and hard to dispute. This raises the question: Why are Chagossians classified as "indigenous"? They never exercised independent control over the islands, were initially transported there by European powers, and resided there for at most 172 years—a duration far shorter than every other culture on Earth, save perhaps the Inuit.

I'm not expert on this, but conceivably it could mean the first inhabitants of something. Who calls them indigenous, BTW?

@IVFcomesfromthetip various activists and international law experts

Doesn't the latter report answer your Q? I assume in 150+ pages they manage to explain from what standpoint they're considered indigenous?! Or is it TLDR?

Lots of countries claim control of their territory despite having been founded a lot later than 200 years ago. And I bet your parents haven't lived in their house for 200 years.

I don't get why you consider 172 years a short time period. It essentially means that nobody alive today has met in person anyone alive before the period started, that is two complete human live times.

@quarague or about 6 or 7 generations of the "my father's father's father" kind.

@quarague it sticks out in the list of indigenous cultures, with just one culture (Greenland Inuit) being potentially disputable. And at least the Inuit had their own culture for thousands of years, compared to a random mix of African tribes and Europeans that was present in Chagos.

@StuartF I know several people whose ancestral home is older than 172 years and they can trace their family tree down till the late 1600s. It’s pretty common in parts of Europe untouched by communism - and is also somewhat common for families in New England.

172 years is also not a huge amount less than 156 (1776 US Independence - 1620 Mayflower).  Or 404 (2024 - 1620).  i.e. be careful when pooh-poohing the lengths of other folks' historical tenures, not everyone can trumpet the CCP's 4000 year of Middle Kingdom history or whatever they are laying claims to.

@ItalianPhilosopher the UK didn’t exactly recognize the 1776 claims either, at least initially :-)

Frame shift
If we forget the specific use of the term "indigenous" for a second and we stick to your concerns about the validity of those claims, you'd find that about the same objections can be applied to the Falkland islanders' claims.
Yet, the UK makes a great big deal about the Falklanders' wishes not to be part of Argentina.
This same logic can be applied to most of the Caribbean islands, where the historical non-white population is almost entirely people imported from Africa. i.e. in much the same boat as the Chagossians.
i.e. Should the ex-colonial power be allowed to do as it pleases and chuck people out from places they have lived for generations?
To me that's the core of the question wrt Chagossians' claims.  The word "indigenous" does seem a bit misused here, at least in the layman's meaning of the word.  Maybe there is a particular UN or human rights aspect that motivates its use and maybe someone else can answer on that basis.
p.s. In the case of the Caribbean, indigenous does refer to the original inhabitants, not the African-descended residents.

Does anyone claim the Falkland Islanders as "indigenous"? Argentina only controlled the islands for 13 years (1820 to 1833), otherwise they were always controlled by France or the UK, hence their primary claim is based off defacto control rather than any "colonization" concerns.

One kind of wonders why they don't just let the people move back to Diego Garcia and offer them well-paying jobs on the base?  Presumably everyone on the base, working in any capacity, from janitors to cooks, is pretty expensive if they have to be motivated to work as expats in the middle of nowhere.  Maybe that has been tried and refused?

Which is why I dodged the use of the term, and addressed the claims instead.

But otherwise my question is specifically about the word "indigenous", not questions of sovereignty per se. And yes - IMO most Carribean residents should not be considered "indigenous".

While the other answer addresses the question more directly, I think this answer better gets at the essential issue. While there are some definitions that would classify the Chagos Islanders as Indigenous, and this may be the best way to ensure their right of return, they all would have some counterintuitive implications if applied more broadly (see my comments under the other answer).

An excessive focus on Indigenous rights here as conceptually separate from human rights or minority rights could even obscure the fundamental issue here—basically, one of ethnic cleansing. After all, if there had (hypothetically) been some small Maldivian population there at the time of colonization, would the UK really be somehow less unjustified in its recent actions? Or it would it be more reasonable for Black Britons to be expelled from the UK?

@ItalianPhilosopher I would guess that people on the island as workers of the MoD will be "at his Majesty pleasure." Meaning that once they are no longer useful, they have to move elsewhere. Legal residents could stay after retirement, have kids, organise political action, protest against the military.

@SJuan76 Not really part of my answer, just some side musing.  Most bases in the US have nearby cities, no?  With locals working there.  There were originally about 3000 Chagossians, right?  That's not a huge amount, Why not house them, permanently, on the unused areas and let those who want to work at the base?  OK, they don't get everything back, but they can if/when US/UK leave and in the meantime, their living standards would be way higher than in Mauritius or living in Chagos without a base.  I am sure this isn't that clever, but it was just a thought.

@ItalianPhilosopher only 1,000 Chagossians at the time of expulsion. But yes - that’s one of the proposals discussed in the literature, see the book linked in my answer for the best overview of the subject.

The report you linked to defends their indigenous status from multiple standpoints, but the one you seem to care about is as I suspected:

Crucially, no other group can claim a prior historical or
ancestral relationship to Chagos and trump the Ilois as Chagos’s first inhabitants.

The report even goes in some detail how that meshes with various (operationalized) definitions of indigenous:

As the first permanent inhabitants of Chagos and with no other group able to claim or
claiming prior habitation, the Ilois meet Daes’s factor of “Priority in time, with respect to the
occupation and use of a specific territory” (1996:22). The Ilois also meet Daes’s factor of having
“an experience of subjugation, marginalization, dispossession, exclusion or discrimination,
whether or not these conditions persist” (1996:22), in both their expulsion from Chagos and their
subsequent lives in Mauritius and Seychelles (as described in 3.5.). For Kingsbury’s framework,
although the Ilois did not live in Chagos for thousands of years, they had nearly 200 years of
continual residence over five or more generations of ancestry. In this way the Ilois also meet
Kingsbury’s “essential requirement” of “long connection with the region” (1998:455).
The Ilois likewise meet Cobo’s underlying emphasis on “historical continuity” in having
occupied the lands of their ancestors going back to the late 18th century and in having “common
ancestry with the original occupants of these lands.” They meet ILO No. 169’s emphasis on
“descent from the populations” originally in a territory. The Ilois actually reach the requirements
of ILO No. 169 in a very literal sense under a strict reading of the convention: Given that the
current state boundaries of Chagos were created in 1965 with the establishment of the BIOT, the
Ilois are the descendants of the “populations which inhabited the country, or a geographical
region to which the country belongs, at the time of conquest or colonization or the establishment
of present state boundaries” (International Labour Organisation 1991:Art. 1; emphasis added).
Though the Ilois do not have the same depth of historical connection with a region or territory as
Aboriginal Australians or the original peoples of the Americas, historical evidence shows that
before their expulsion, the Ilois had a strong, ongoing, and lengthy ancestral connection with the
Chagos Archipelago and its original inhabitants. With no other group of people able to claim
prior habitation or historical connection with the islands, the evidence strongly suggests that the
Ilois meet the general requirement of having a historical and temporal connection with Chagos
and its ancestral inhabitants.


That source is extremely biased and doesn’t even try to discuss a single counter argument. Plus it’s now outdated: the UK Supreme Court has ruled against the “Chagossians” in 2016, overriding the 2000 ruling.

@JonathanReez: ok, so since you'd only accept that the answer is no, I'm VTC this as "promote or discredit". It's not a real Q if you've already made up your mind before "asking".

I’m happy to accept any source that tries to actually argue against the counter arguments. Unfortunately this particular paper is very one sided and doesn’t respond to alternative opinions.

@JonathanReez: that's just filibustering from you. You know very well there can't be any "counter arguments" if you make it a hard requirement that they'd have to have lived there for 1000 years.

I don't think any of the definitions are uncomplicated. It's easy to see issues with  "priority in time": by that standard, if new archeological evidence showed that, say, Indigenous North Americans actually crossed the Bering Strait in multiple waves, with some populations descended from the one and some descended from others, some would be rendered non-indigenous, which seems like an unhelpful definition. Or only the Puebloans would be Indigenous New Mexicans, and not, say, the Diné.

Focusing on "ILO No. 169 in a very literal sense under a strict reading of the convention" also does not seem without its problems. Since this argument bases its definition of "Indigenous" on the establishment of current state boundaries,  it would lend itself to such counterintuitive arguments as saying that descendants of European or Black Americans present before 1776 counted as Indigenous in the USA, which again, would not seem like the most useful definition.

An issue with "descent from populations originally in a territory" seems clear as well: by that definition, some descendants of Maldivians, even if not actually present in the Chagos Islands, might qualify, and the Chagos islanders might not, again kind of counterintuitive. (If interpreted as only applying to actual long-term residence across several generations, it still would lend itself to the kind of archeological problems mentioned previously; e.g. finding evidence of a small long-vanished Maldivian settlement would matter, even though intuitively it would seem that it should not).

@Obie2.0 according to the latter definition Greenland should be given away to the Swedes, as they discovered and settled it first.

Finally, "an experience of subjugation, marginalization, dispossession, exclusion or discrimination, whether or not these conditions persist" (while obviously meant to be taken in conjunction with one or more other factors) also has issues. On the one hand, it seems to make being Indigenous intrinsically tied to oppression (were Indigenous Americans not Indigenous before European colonization?); on the other, it allows for some interesting assertions such as declaring that Dalits are Indigenous while Brahmins are not (both are descended from original inhabitants and Dalits are oppressed).

Actually, that definition is one of the most thorny because its breadth probably accomplishes the opposite of what it intends to do (presumably, to exclude nationally relatively privileged groups that are nonetheless descended from early inhabitants from its definition). For instance, imagine a rich White French person declaring that their group needs to have Indigenous rights (however defined) because Germany subjugated France during the second world war ("...whether or not these conditions persist.")

Or things like declaring that, say, someone of both Romani and German ancestry living in Germany is Indigenous (Descended from the earliest inhabitants? Check. Subject to past or in fact current discrimination? Check.)

None of which is to say that the Chagos Islanders should not be considered Indigenous, particularly if that is the only or most reliable way to ensure that they or their descendants can return to the homeland, but they definitely are not unproblematic criteria.

@Obie2.0: please write an answer instead of 7 comments to mine.

The comments don't constitute an answer because they are neither a suggestion that Chagos Islanders are not Indigenous, nor providing a source saying that they are. They are if anything providing possible improvements to this answer (i.e. reservations about the implications of the argumentation of the source that it is based on that could be incorporated therein).

IVFcomesfromthetip  So you don't like repeat comments on your answers?  Whodathought  @Obie2.0 but, yeah, maybe an answer would be a better vehicle.  Nothing wrong with pointing out that "indigenous" is not always an easy trait to determine.  Nor that it's usage to influence human rights legislation and policy can be fraught and ill-suited in certain cases.

@Obie2.0 interestingly Mauritius denies the idea that Chagossians are an indigenous people: source: " 94 The Mauritian government has objected to the Chagossians’ claim of Indigeneity saying that they constituted a segment of the wider Mauritian people." So clearly it's not just the UK government who thinks their claims are... questionable.

Update: looks like the indigenous aspect is 100% moot now. Mauritius got the land back and has no intention of giving any special rights to “Chagossians”. Removed my answer as irrelevant.
